# populating A Class that has another class as a property

Tags: c#, class, oop, design-patterns, properties

I Have two classes in my windows form application.
Let's say `Student` and `StudentDetails` where by the class `StudentDetails` is also a property of `Student` class.

I Have a stored procedure which gets data from both tables in the database.
I need to know how is it that this scenario is usually handled meaning how is Student Class Usually populated.
Thanks a lot for your Answers.
Any link to a similar scenario wold be great.

here is my code:

```
 class Student
    {
        public int StudentID { get; set; }
        public string StudentName { get; set; }
        public StudentDetails StudentDetails { get; set; }

        public Student()
        {
            this.StudentID = 0;
            this.StudentName = String.Empty;
            this.StudentDetails = new StudentDetails();
        }

    }

class StudentDetails
    {

        public int StudentDetailsID { get; set; }
        public string Address { get; set; }
        public int Height { get; set; }
        public int Weight { get; set; }

        public StudentDetails()
        {
            this.StudentDetailsID = 0;
            this.Address = String.Empty;
            this.Height = 0;
            this.Weight = 0;

        }

    }
```

The below class has a function that fills the Student Class (**FillStudent()** )

```
 Class StudentAssembler
        {

            public List<Model.Student> FillStudent()
            {
                List<Model.Student> StudentCollection = new List<Model.Student>();
                Model.Student StudentDTO = new Model.Student();
                try
                {
                    using (Model.dbConnection dbconnection = new Model.dbConnection(Utilities.SqlConnStr))
                    {

                        SqlDataReader dr;
                        SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("GetStudents", dbconnection.connection);
                        command.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                        dbconnection.OpenConn();
                        dr = command.ExecuteReader();
                        while (dr.Read())
                        {
                            StudentDTO.StudentID = dr[0] == DBNull.Value ? 0 : (int)dr[0];
                            StudentDTO.StudentName = dr[1] == DBNull.Value ? String.Empty : (String)dr[1];

//this is the part that i need to know how is it usually handled

//StudentDTO.StudentDetails = how to fill out this part ???
                                StudentCollection.Add(StudentDTO);
                            }

                            return StudentCollection;
                        }
                    }
                    catch (Exception)
                    {
                        return null;
                    }
                }
            }
```

**EDIT:**

Stored Procedure Code

```
select s.StudentID,s.StudentName,sd.StudentDetailsID,sd.Address,
sd.Height,sd.Weight
from Student s,StudentDetails sd
where s.StudentID = sd.StudentID
```

Comment: It depends on what "GetStudents" procedure returns. If the details are in there, you could simply create a new instance of StudentDetails and set the properties. This is not really a good way to handle this kind of thing? Why not use Entity Framework?

Comment: @Pseudonym: "code broke, please help" is explicitly off topic at Code Review. Take a moment to review what kind of questions can be asked there: http://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask

Comment: @Pseudonym thanks for you comment ,Actually i am not working with the posted code i only put it as an example i just need help finding how to deal with a similar scenario what is the best practice or best design pattern :)

Comment: @Andrew Stored procedure Code is posted and thanks Alot

Comment: @nayefharb Seems like your procedure returns everything you need. I posted an answer with an easy fix.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you have two options

1: a seperate sproc (or sql) to get info from tthe student detail table by studentID. call this per student

2: join the student details table in your sproc/sql and populate both with the same row of data

option 1: is generally cleaner and more reusable. I would say that this should be your first approach.

However, if you need to retrieve many students option 2 will be much faster. as it only needs a single call to the db.

Also you seem to have a 1 to 1 relationship between the student and studendetails so there is no reason not to use option 2. If however you have many details to one student, you can still use option 2, skipping the duplicate student info. This can often be the best way even though you are returning more data than required from the sql

Comment: regarding the first option that first my first attempt but i Thought to look for better ways if exist. regarding the second option correct me if i am wrong ,I will now have 3 DataObjects Student, StudentDetails and a separate one for my Stored Procedure I thinks this will cause  unnecessary Code duplication.

Comment: you dont need to create a third dto, just populate both

Answer (score 1):

Considering the stored procedure query, you could simply:

```
StudentDTO.StudentDetails = new StudentDetails
{
    StudentDetailsID = dr[2] == DBNull.Value ? 0 : (int)dr[2],
    Address = dr[3] == DBNull.Value ? String.Empty : (String)dr[3],
    ...
};
```

Answer (score 0):

You could create separate functions to get Student and Student Details records.
This way you could re-use those functions everywhere in the code.

E.g. for `student` you could have a function like this

```
  public Student CreateStudent(IDataRecord iDataRecord)
    {
        Student stud = new Student();
        stud.Id = GetValue<int>(iDataRecord, "Id");
        stud.Name = GetValue<string>(iDataRecord, "Name");
        return stud;
    }
```

for `studentDetails`, create a function like this :

```
      public StudentDetails CreateStudentDetails(IDataRecord iDataRecord)
    {
        StudentDetails studDetails = new StudentDetails();
        studDetails.Id = GetValue<int>(iDataRecord, "Id");
        studDetails.Address = GetValue<string>(iDataRecord, "Address");
        studDetails.Height = GetValue<string>(iDataRecord, "Height");
        studDetails.Weight = GetValue<string>(iDataRecord, "Weight");
        return studDetails;
    }
```

Then, in your `FillStudent` method, simply call:

```
Student student=this.CreateStudent(dr);
student.StudentDetails=this.CreateStudentDetails(dr);
```

Please note that, this code is for illustration purpose only. You could further re-factor this code to place it separately creating factory classes.